# Can I implement an iOS App to act as a BLE service?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, bluetooth-peripheral

Can I implement an iOS App to act as a Bluetooth low energy service?

I need to be able to programmatically define:

- a service UUID
- characteristics for the service
- a way to update the values of these
- a way to define the user permission of the characteristics: read / write / notify
- a way to define the transmission (TX) power of the service

Would appreciate if you could point me out to a good demo / example to get started or even share some code snippet so this can become part of the Documentation of iOS.

Comment: Not transmission power, but `CBPeripheraManager` does all the rest. See also https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/703/ for extensive discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Core Bluetooth guide as throughly as possible, especially setting up a Peripheral Service:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1

Keep in mind that if you are looking to adjust these parameters you need to pay attention to how iOS changes the BLE data structure being emitted when in background mode / inactive state.